# Как убрать расстояние между списками listView

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

Есть LinearLayout. В нем 3 ListView. В ListView я не ставлю никаких вертикальных разделителей, но при отображении между 2 и 3 ListView есть расстояние и после 3-го тоже расстояние между ним и границей LinearLayout. [image: picture]

Мой file.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
........

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_height="330dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/material_background"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/hours_list"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="313dp"
            android:dividerHeight="7dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/minutes_list"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="313dp"
            android:dividerHeight="7dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/day_of_time_list"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="313dp"
            android:dividerHeight="7dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: задайте для @+id/view layout_width конкретное значение, а у дочерних ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: @ Tiarait, спаисбо. воспользовалась Вашим советом и советом @ Barmaley♦ по поводу внутренних отступов.

Answer (score 5):

Судя по всему вам надо убрать `margin` между списками. Заодно можно и поиграться с `padding` - разница между ними на иллюстрации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дак у него вроде нет margin-ов

Comment: Зависит от текущего стиля... Вручную надо поставить `layout_margin="0dp"` и посмотреть

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka их нет в разметке которую предоставил автор вопроса, но они есть в разметке элемента списка. И кажется это стандартные отступы для `ListView`, если их нужно удалить, нужно создать свой макет списка и убрать все отступы. UPD: [нагуглено](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15344510/9271527)

Comment: воспользовалась @ Tiarait советом и советом @ Barmaley♦ по поводу внутренних отступов. так сказать "подогнала")